# excel text spilling into adjacent cells on BOTH sides under certain alignment conditions when text is too long

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have this issue that only crops up after running a vba to concatenate cells while retaining the original formats (using right to left characters).
When the sheet is set left-to-right, or if alignment is set to 'left' or 'center' it worked fine, but when the sheet is right-to-left and alignment is set to 'right' it starts spilling over if the text is longer 1024 characters.

You can see in this image that the text spills from C2 (~4300 chars) into the previous cells in row 2, blocking their content (it spills into column D as well, but that's expected since D2 is empty).
C1 (~2200 chars)  which is aligned 'center' and has no spilling into column B (it does spill into D1 which is empty, as expected)

[image]

I can't set alignment to 'fill' because then I lose the different formats inside the cell. Wrapping text won't help either because then I lose half my screen to that cell. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing languages of English, which is left-to-right, and Hebrew,
which is right-to-left.

It's therefore natural that English will spill to the right, while
Hebrew will spill to the left.

Mixing different-direction text is most applications is very chancy,
not only in Excel. You need to understand the limitations of the tool
you're using, because the behavior of the tool itself is not modifiable,
except by the developers of the tool.

Comment: It's Hebrew only. There is no left-to-right text in C2. In any case, it's not supposed to spill into cells with text. The issue is that the text spills into the right, which should never happen when text is right-to-left.

Comment: Older products like Office were originally written for Latin languages. Only later were added Unicode and languages like Hebrew. I don't know of any product, old or new, in which such a mixture of languages is supported in a way that makes total sense for a human being. As I said, one has to adapt to incomplete implementations.